# Ajax - API Endpoint - Is this the right way to do?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring

I'm having a encoding issue when I send a AJAX request to an API Endpoint.

I have this Endpoint in the code below using Java Spring:

```
@Autowired
    ApiKeyRepository apiKeyRepository;  

    @RequestMapping(value= "/weather/{cityName}/{fuCity}/now",  method = {RequestMethod.GET}, produces="application/json" )
        public ResponseEntity<Weather> getWeatherNowByCityName(@PathVariable(value = "cityName") String cityName,  @PathVariable(value = "fuCity") State fuCity) throws JSONException, ParseException, java.text.ParseException {

        String newCityName = cityName.toLowerCase();

            try {

                newCityName = URLDecoder.decode(newCityName , "UTF-8").replace(" ", "%20");         

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        String weatherEndpoint = "/api/v1/locale/city?name=" + newCityName + "&state=" + fuCity.toString();

        String appToken = apiKeyRepository.getByservice("climaTempo");

        URL weatherDomain = new URL("http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br" + weatherEndpoint + "&token=" + appToken);

        /// From here I send a JSON Request to the 'weatherDomain' to get the Weather from the city and her state that I get from the EndPoint Parameters
    }
```

And I send this jQuery Ajax request to the Endpoint:

```
var uf = $("#colWeather #selectState").val();
var city = $("#colWeather #selectCity").val();

$.ajax({
       url: host + '/weather/' + city + '/' + uf + '/now',
       type: 'GET',
       contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
       async: true
 }).done(function (JSONReturn) {
       //Actions with JSONReturn
 });
```

But here in Brazil we have some cities with accents and cedilla like "Avaí" from "SP", "Mairiporã" from "SP" and "Missão Velha" from "CE".

If I send to the Endpoint an URL like "/weather/Americana/SP/now" or "/weather/Piracicaba/SP/now" the Endpoint gets the JSON return without problems.

But if I send to the Endpoint an URL like "/weather/Mairiporã/SP/now" or "/weather/Avaí/SP/now" the ClimaTempo API returns a null JSON and I get a NullPointerException.

I'm thinking that is a problem with the accents, but I can't send just "/weather/Mairipora/SP/now" without the accents because the ClimaTempo API demands that the city name must go with the accents, otherwise it returns a null JSON...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use [`encodeURIComponent(city)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode and decode your characters.

---

## Encode in JavaScript

Instead of `url: host + '/weather/' + city + '/' + uf + '/now'`, go for

```js
url: host + '/weather/' + encodeURIComponent(city) + '/' + uf + '/now'
```

---

## Decode in Java

Instead of `String newCityName = cityName.toLowerCase();`, go for

```java
String newCityName = URLDecoder.decode(cityName, Charsets.UTF_8.name()).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: You are the man. I spent about 2 days trying to fix this problem